# How to obtain a confidence interval or a measure of prediction dispersion when using xgboost for classification?

Tags: machine-learning, confidence-interval, xgboost

How to obtain a confidence interval or a measure of prediction dispersion when using xgboost for classification?

So for example, if xgboost predicts a probability of an event is 0.9, how can the confidence in that probability be obtained?

Also is this confidence assumed to be heteroskedastic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To produce confidence intervals for xgboost model you should train several models (you can use bagging for this). Each model will produce a response for test sample - all responses will form a distribution from which you can easily compute confidence intervals using basic statistics. You should produce response distribution for each test sample.

Comment: I propose to run 100 models (the more the better ) and check in what range 95% of values lays. The response variable is homoscedastic.

Comment: The mean and standard deviation of the predictions is NOT the same as a confidence interval.

Comment: Of course that mean and std of predictions is different thing than confidence intervals - the question was how to compute confidence intervals and I gave a recipe for this

Comment: Hello @pplonski, in what do the 100 models differ? just the seed, or the training data too? Thanks

Comment: just change seed